# ALT text to display above image onclick

Tags: jquery, image, touch

For regular desktop users the alt/title of the image displays on :hover so that's all good but for mobile users they can't see it so I would like to let them be able to see the ALT text positioned with absolute right above the image onclick.

Here's what I got:

```
<img class="prize" title="Best" src="/images/best.png" alt="Best" />
```

Comment: Okay, and could you please share, what you have tried already ?

Comment: I only got the image at this point. Been searching around on this website but the closest i got was to display the alt text ON the image.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [figcaptions](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp) which are set to display on mobile view ports only by media query or bootstrap.

It's gonna get hard with CSS only cause img elements have no content to add to, you could try to wrap the img with a div which gets a title and use something like `div::before { content: attr(title) }`:

```css
div::before {content: attr(title) }
```

```html
<div title="img title"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif" alt="alt text" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is working solution : [working solution at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bluedextermini/enw7ax0L/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imgId').click(function() {
    console.log('image clicked, place your code here');
    $('#altDivId').addClass('imgAlt');
    $('#altDivId').html($('#imgId').attr('alt'));
    //setting left
    $('#altDivId').css('left', $('#imgId').position().left +  ($('#imgId').width() - $('#altDivId').width()));
    //setting top
    $('#altDivId').css('top', $('#imgId').position().top);

   

  });
});
```

```css
div.imgAlt {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='imgId' src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt='alternate txt'>
<div id='altDivId'>
```